# Extract the last value from column (Sqlite)

Tags: sqlite

Can I extract the last value of column like I have a column:

```
column_name
12 23 45 67
33 44 55 99 100
11 22
99 08 08
111 222 909 707 6
```

I need a resulting column

```
67
100
22
08
6
```

Comment: Having a relational database column store multiple values is a sure sign of a database design mistake. One result of such a design mistake is the problem you are now having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select replace(column_name, rtrim(Text, replace(Text, ' ', '')), '') from table_name;
```

What this does is:

- get a temporary string with all spaces removed, e.g. '12234567'
- use rtrim to remove from the right those characters from temporary string up to first space -> '12 23 45 '
- replace from the original text the value from the rtrim operation to get only the last value -> 65

Comment: Super solution. Thanks.